# MySQL Hotel Room total fee query based on dates

Tags: mysql

I need to query a small hotel reservation system and I need help with the a query to get the rooms available on a specific set of dates with the total fees for the room.

The table looks like this:

```
+--------+------------+-------+--------+-------+------------------+
| RoomId | Date       | ResID |  Rate  | Tax   | DailyCleaningFee |
+--------+------------+-------+--------+-------+------------------+
|    1   | 2019-01-01 |   0   | 100    | 0.130 |    30            |
+--------+------------+-------+--------+-------+------------------+
```

ResID determines if the room is booked on certain dates or not. 0 being room available.
I want to query all rooms available for 2 nights on specific cates, and it should also return Total rate for the room including cleaning fee and taxes resulting in a table like this:

```
+---------+------------+
| RoomId  | TotalRate |
+-------- +------------+
```

If I want to query my table for 2 nights, 2019-01-02 and 2019-01-03, it should also exclude records where Tax is null and/or if the rate is set to 0. What would my query look like?

Really grateful for any help I can get.
Thank you!

Edit:
I added a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/innhbDSpjxLFXd4jNtXYGj/3) link to an example of the table.

Comment: Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: You have a table that records the fee for every room for every date? That's erm...

Comment: @Strawberry That's the way it is setup right now, would you recommend to create another table for rates? Rates can be different every day.

Comment: How are rates determined?

Comment: @Strawberry Set by the user manually.

Comment: The user manually configured a price for every room for every day? That must keep them busy.

Comment: It's just a little project I'm working on to get a grasp on what to do and what not to do. I do agree that manually entering the data for every room every day is not realistic/extremely time consuming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is missing some information to answer it accurately. But I think I can help you to understand what your query should look like to get the expected result. See below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   t1.RoomId AS RoomId, 
   (((t1.Rate + t1.DailyCleaningFee) * (1.0 + t1.Tax)) + ((t2.Rate + t2.DailyCleaningFee) * (1.0 + t2.Tax))) AS TotalRate  -- total rate has been the sum of each day rate + tax
FROM (
    SELECT h.*
    FROM `Hotel` h
    WHERE h.Date = '2018-12-02'   -- your first date goes here
    AND h.ResID = 0 AND h.Tax IS NOT NULL AND h.Rate > 0
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT h.*
    FROM `Hotel` h
    WHERE h.Date = '2018-12-03'  -- your second date goes here
    AND h.ResID = 0 AND h.Tax IS NOT NULL AND h.Rate > 0
) t2 ON t1.RoomId = t2.RoomId
```

This works, because, for each date you are searching (here you mentioned for two days), you need to have an inner query, and then you need to join all together by `RoomId` to collect rooms available in all of provided dates. After then only you can calculate the final rate.

You may have to modify tax calculation formula which you have not clearly mentioned.

---

**Edit:** (2018-12-01)

*Above query valid only explicitly for two days.*

To calculate total rate for **any number of continuous days**, you can use following query.

```
SELECT
    t1.RoomId AS RoomId,
    ROUND(SUM(t1.DailyRate), 2) AS TotalRate
FROM (
    SELECT
        h.RoomId,
        ((h.Rate + h.DailyCleaningFee) * (1.0 + h.Tax)) AS DailyRate
    FROM Hotel h
    WHERE
        h.ResID = 0 
        AND h.Tax IS NOT NULL 
        AND h.Rate > 0
        AND h.Date >= '2018-12-02' AND h.Date <= '2018-12-04'
) t1
GROUP BY
    t1.RoomId
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= DATEDIFF('2018-12-04', '2018-12-02') + 1;
```

Note that the dates are inclusive in both boundaries. Replace hardcoded dates with your date parameters.
In `HAVING` clause we check whether there are continuous days available from a single room for all days, and only filters them.

According to @Strawberry it might not be the efficient way to store room charges in a kind of given table. You may need to change the schema little bit to make it gain more performance.

Comment: I think this is trying to fix the problem from the wrong end

Comment: @Strawberry I know. It is a weird table, but since he was asking `What would my query look like?` (as in the question), I showed it to him.

Comment: @isuru89 Thank you for your reply. Your query does work as intended.

The tax calculation is right being: (rate + dailycleaningrate) * tax for each day.

Now if I wanted to query available rooms + totalrate for multiple nights, say 4-5 nights. I am not sure how that would work with Inner Join?

Comment: @WhistlePig I edited my answer to reflect what you are asking. Check it and let me know.